# Angular 2+: how to remove all angular attributes and comments (and other angular artifacts) from the HTML code?

Tags: angular

I want to utilise Angular in a not really usual way. I use it to generate the HTML that is later on used for various needs.

Why? I want this HTML to be static and independent from angular. E.g. if I change my app and e.g. refactor the code the generated HTML should be the same (of course if the logic behind is the same) which is not possible with `_ngcontent-cXXX` variables and comments with ngif / ngfor that really depend on the version / structure of the app. In other words, the HTML generation function should be deterministic.

Problem is that the generated HTML is not really clean. E.g.

```
<p _ngcontent-c8="">
  Hello

  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->

  blabla

  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->

  ciao
</p>
```

How to get rid of all those attributes / comments / etc? Does Angular provide us with some utilities / services to clean up the HTML string?

HTML minifier / replace function would be a simple-and-dirty way to go here but I really want this thing to be relying on some of the Angular standard functionalities.

Comment: Remove Angular from your project ;-) What does "not really clean" mean exactly? Angular adds these for a reason.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer He wants the outputted HTML that Angular generates. I don't think that was difficult to understand from his question.

Comment: @cgTag not sure what you mean with your comment. I got that he wants the attributes removed, but I don't understand why he thinks having them in the DOM is "not clean".

Comment: @smnbbrv if you set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` at least the `_ngcontent-xx` attributes will go away, but you also lose style encapsulation.

Comment: Maybe he wants to generate HTML and give it to people who aren't interested in seeing a bunch of internal Angular attributes and comments. I think the term "not clean" is an accurate description. But hay, I'm not trying to argue here. We're going off topic. :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  In this case think of angular like of something really simple e.g. Handlebars where you render the template based on some data. I have an angular app and don't want another library to generate HTML. I need to share this HTML with other tools later e.g. for generating PDF files. So, I want to get rid of all the attributes that don't make sense to me because none of them adds any value (in this particular scenario) to the HTML code.

Comment: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is a good hint, thanks. As long as I don't use style encapsulation (I share HTML so I need to share global styles instead) this is a half of solution

Comment: From your use case it seems it's more about one-time removal, just before you generate the HTML, so basically you can scrap the HTML from your current page, then tidy the HTML up and then use it to generate PDF (like cgTag mentioned in his answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to post-process the HTML using a library such as [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Tidy has options to strip attributes that aren't on a white-list and also remove comments, but it's a library and has to be run on a string or text file.

Tidy can be run via different platforms like PHP, NodeJS or .NET. Here's a NodeJS library:

https://github.com/vavere/htmltidy

Another option would be to use jQuery to update the DOM using a broad `$('*').each()` and just mutate the DOM elements before saving the HTML to where you need it.

Comment: looks like this is what I was afraid of - cleaning HTML manually :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you need to set the `ViewEncapsulation` to None. Understanding how this works is key, as these dynamically generated classes you do not want are there for the reason of specificity.

According to the Angular 4 [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation):

- Emulated: Provides a surrogate attribute, to allow each component to be absolutely independent, as if it were a [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) (which is why the dynamic class is being added...again to allow it to be independent due to specificity.
- Native: Will utilise (excuse my British spelling) the Shadow DOM and as far as I am aware, will therefore not generate classes, because it can live independently. However using this may fail in certain browsers which do not support the Shadow DOM.
- None: I believe this is what you need, as it will not "provide any template or style encapsulation" as stated. In other words, you won't see the generated classes. However this could cause encapsulation issues, which is why you may want to avoid it.

To do this, use the following code in your component file (in the component [decorator function](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#metadata-overview):

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Comment: this won't remove the ng-if comments though

Comment: Your initial question is about removing &quot;all&quot; angular attributes&quot; from the HTML. What you are now asking is for ng-if statements only, which cannot be removed as they are necessary for handling the conditional logic in certain scenarios in Angular. This issue has been closed on the official repository for Angular 4: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8722#issue

You can try to remove the comments manually as discussed in the comments, but I believe this will cause internal issues in Angular.

Comment: updated the question to also point to removal of the comments. My goal is to have a clean HTML without variable angular tags / comments and any other Angular artifacts. Funny that most of the comments / answers don't try to understand the problem before giving the comments / answers and judge by the question title that just cannot handle all the things I want to ask

Comment: Thanks for updating, apologies if you think i've missed the point. No problem. What you want at the moment is possible for styling. You can use the encapsulation object, set to none to solve this. 

Then in terms of removing the ng-if comment, I would suggest not doing this because Angular needs it to handle conditions in some cases.

If you have any further questions, feel free to shout :)